# How can I programmatically apply text formats?

Tags: 8, input-formats

I've created a custom text format I'm trying to apply to a field programmatically. As best I can tell, the format IS getting applied, but it is not stripping HTML tags like it is supposed to. The below screenshot shows how my text formatter is configured:

[image]

As you can see, its supposed to filter `<span>` tags. The Nodes where this will be used get created programmatically, and I apply the text formatter as follows:

```php
'field_career_job_description1' => ['value' => $job['jobdesc'],'format' => 'careers_html_formatter']
```

This appears to be working correctly, if I print the variables passed to twig, I see that the formatter is, indeed, my custom format:

[image]

However, as you can see in the sshot, `<span>` tags are still in the text.

Note that I am displaying the field in question in Twig as follows:

`{{ content.field_career_job_description1[0]['#text'] | raw }}`

Comment: Kindly avoid pasting code as screenshots. This is bad for accessibility, discoverability and reproducing issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I was pressing post on this question, I realized the problem. It's the twig code. In order to get the text formatter properly applied, I had to call my field as follows:

`{{ content.field_career_job_description1 }}`

Leaving this question up because I couldn't find anything like it on google

Comment: Glad you found the answer - but you should accept it, even if it's your own.